# Multiple Records being fetched in Cursor PLSQL Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, procedure, oracle-ebs

**Table : WSH_DEL_DETAILS_INTERFACE**

**Unique Column:DELIVERY_DETAIL_INTERFACE_ID**

**Input to procedure** : DELIVERY_DETAIL_INTERFACE_ID

Column values to be fetched:**SALES_ORDER_LINE_NUMBER** , **SALES_ORDER_NUMBER**

**Expected Output:**
Single record

**Actual Output:**
All records in table are being fetched

**Code:**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE procedurevalidation(
delivery_detail_interface_id IN 
WSH_DEL_DETAILS_INTERFACE.DELIVERY_DETAIL_INTERFACE_ID%TYPE,
ROW_COUNT OUT INTEGER)
IS
CURSOR wddi_cur IS SELECT *  FROM WSH_DEL_DETAILS_INTERFACE WHERE 
DELIVERY_DETAIL_INTERFACE_ID = delivery_detail_interface_id;
wddi_record WSH_DEL_DETAILS_INTERFACE%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

OPEN wddi_cur;

LOOP

FETCH wddi_cur into wddi_record;
EXIT when wddi_cur%NOTFOUND;

DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(100000);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(delivery_detail_interface_id);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SALESORDERNUMBER111:::: ' || 
wddi_record.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SALESORDERLINENUMBER1111::::: ' || 
wddi_record.SALES_ORDER_LINE_NUMBER);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COUNT' || ROW_COUNT);

END LOOP;
CLOSE wddi_cur;


end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the names of the input variable to your procedure.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE procedurevalidation(
p_delivery_detail_interface_id IN 
WSH_DEL_DETAILS_INTERFACE.DELIVERY_DETAIL_INTERFACE_ID%TYPE,
ROW_COUNT OUT INTEGER)
```

And in your cursor you need to change the variable name as well.

```
CURSOR wddi_cur 
    IS 
SELECT *  
  FROM WSH_DEL_DETAILS_INTERFACE 
 WHERE DELIVERY_DETAIL_INTERFACE_ID = p_delivery_detail_interface_id;
```

Your cursor is returning all records in the table because you are equating the table's column itself and not matching it with the input variable in the procedure